# JMS Transactions in Mule 2

Tags: jms, mule

I tried setting this up for my project and it appears to work in the sense that a request is placed back on the queue if I kill  Tomcat before it finishes. But if I let it run I get an exception.

The only thing I changed was adding the JMS transaction line below to a service that otherwise works fine. Is there a bug in Mule 2 or is there something else I need to do?

```
<service name="ChangeService">
    <inbound>
        <jms:inbound-endpoint
                connector-ref="jmsConnectorWMQ"
                address="${change.service.inbound.endpoint}?method=applyListToRecords"
                transformer-refs="Jms2Obj TraceRouteInbound"
                responseTransformer-refs="DiagnosticsXForm TraceRouteOutbound MessagePropertiesTransformer Obj2Jms">
            <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
        </jms:inbound-endpoint>
    </inbound>

    <component>
        <interceptor-stack ref="InterceptorStack"/>
        <spring-object bean="service"/>
    </component>
</service>
```

The exception:

```
ERROR [asyncDelivery4][2012-10-18 13:52:21,123] - org.oclc.mule.interceptors.FaultHandlingInterceptor Invocation failed:
org.mule.api.service.ServiceException: Component that caused exception is: SedaService{ChangeServiceAnyXml}. Message payload is of type: JMSTextMessage
    at org.mule.component.DefaultLifecycleAdapter.invoke(DefaultLifecycleAdapter.java:216)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.invokeComponentInstance(AbstractJavaComponent.java:83)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.doInvoke(AbstractJavaComponent.java:74)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.invokeInternal(AbstractComponent.java:133)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.intercept(AbstractComponent.java:93)
    at org.mule.component.ComponentInterceptorInvoker.invoke(ComponentInterceptorInvoker.java:52)
    at org.mule.interceptor.InterceptorStack$Invoc.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:70)
    at org.mule.api.interceptor.Invocation$invoke.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at org.oclc.mule.interceptors.FaultHandlingInterceptor.intercept(FaultHandlingInterceptor.groovy:39)
    at org.mule.interceptor.InterceptorStack$Invoc.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:65)
    at org.mule.api.interceptor.Invocation$invoke.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at org.oclc.mule.interceptors.StatsLoggingInterceptor.intercept(StatsLoggingInterceptor.groovy:37)
    at org.mule.interceptor.InterceptorStack$Invoc.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:65)
    at org.mule.interceptor.InterceptorStack.intercept(InterceptorStack.java:46)
    at org.mule.component.ComponentInterceptorInvoker.invoke(ComponentInterceptorInvoker.java:48)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.invoke(AbstractComponent.java:165)
    at org.mule.service.AbstractService.invokeComponent(AbstractService.java:921)
    at org.mule.model.seda.SedaService.doSend(SedaService.java:256)
    at org.mule.service.AbstractService.sendEvent(AbstractService.java:499)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleSession.sendEvent(DefaultMuleSession.java:359)
    at org.mule.routing.inbound.DefaultInboundRouterCollection.send(DefaultInboundRouterCollection.java:228)
    at org.mule.routing.inbound.DefaultInboundRouterCollection.route(DefaultInboundRouterCollection.java:188)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver$DefaultInternalMessageListener.onMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:382)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:258)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:203)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractReceiverWorker$1.doInTransaction(AbstractReceiverWorker.java:147)
    at org.mule.transaction.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:117)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractReceiverWorker.doRun(AbstractReceiverWorker.java:165)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractReceiverWorker.run(AbstractReceiverWorker.java:67)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:310)
    at org.mule.work.SyncWorkExecutor.doExecute(SyncWorkExecutor.java:41)
    at org.mule.work.MuleWorkManager.executeWork(MuleWorkManager.java:287)
    at org.mule.work.MuleWorkManager.doWork(MuleWorkManager.java:180)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.MultiConsumerJmsMessageReceiver$SubReceiver.onMessage(MultiConsumerJmsMessageReceiver.java:316)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageConsumer.receiveAsync(MQMessageConsumer.java:2969)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.SessionAsyncHelper.run(SessionAsyncHelper.java:406)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: What version of mule 2 are you using?